# EF: The instance of entity type X cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am sending a User entity in Json format in my http request like this:

```
POST http://localhost:52054/api/Authentication/DeleteAccessToken HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:52054
Content-Type: application/json

{"id":1,"userName":"mnoureldin","accessToken":{"id":1,"token":"123ABC456EFG","userId":1}}
```

And my controller (in **EF-core**) handles that like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DeleteAccessToken([FromBody]User user)
{
    using (var Context = new UnitOfWork().Context)
    {
        var userEntity = Context.Users.Find(user.Id); // Get the real entity of the user received as json
        if (userEntity != null)
        {
            var accessTokenEntity = Context.AccessTokens.Find(userEntity.AccessToken.Id); // Find the entity of the accesstoken (I tried also directly by accessing the navigation property of user entity)
            Context.AccessTokens.Remove(accessTokenEntity);
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
    }
}
```

But the line `Context.AccessTokens.Remove(accessTokenEntity);` throws this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The instance of entity type 'AccessToken'
>   cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same
>   key is already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key
>   types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set
>   (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for its type).
>   If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they
>   do not collide with existing entities or temporary values generated
>   for other new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that
>   only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the
>   context.

I tried also accessing the AccessToken navigation property directly from userEntity with the same exception.

Here is my UnitOfWork initialization:

```
public UnitOfWork()
{
    // Configure EF connection
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CustomDbContext>();
    optionsBuilder
        .UseMySQL(@"server=192.168.1.35; port=3306; sslmode=none;
                    userid=root;
                    pwd=P@ssword;
                    database=dotnet;");

    Context = new CustomDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

    // Configure data loading method to explicit
    Context.AccessTokens.Load();
}
```

My CustomBdContext:

```
public class CustomDbContext : DbContext
{
    // Tell EF to map the entities to tables
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AccessToken> AccessTokens { get; set; }

    public CustomDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

I have the following simple data model with **one to one** relationship:

```
User ----- AccessToken
```

User:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual AccessToken AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

AccessToken:

```
public class AccessToken
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User"), Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Could someone help me to solve that? I didn't understand what is exactly happening..

Comment: First question: where is `Context` initialized?

Comment: @GertArnold Yes by debugging the both `userEntity` and `accessTokenEntity` vars are being fetched from the database.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. Where do you initialize the `Context` itself? That's always the first essential part of information when looking at this "already being tracked" error.

Comment: @Evk I edited the question, do you mean like this? if yes, that is actually what I am doing, but I didn't show that to make the code as simple as possible.

Comment: Well it turns out in your case it is something different (I bet it is Context.AccessTokens.Load - why are you doing this), so I deleted that comment.

Comment: Although `Context.AccessTokens.Load();` seems a strange thing to do in a context factory (which your "UnitOfWork" essentially is), it still doesn't explain the error. The currently visible code doesn't seem to give rise to duplication of attached entities anywhere. `Find` will always try to find an attached entity first.

Comment: @Evk I am doing this here because EF-Core doesn't support lazy loading, and I think it is the easiest way to be able to access AccessToken navigation property in user entity (an no lazy loading is available yet in EF-Core).

Comment: @GertArnold see the previous comment please, but where would you put that .load() if not in UnitOfWork? of how would you load the navigation properties of each entity when no lazy loading is available? using `include` for each statement?

Comment: `Load` explains why not getting NRE on `userEntity.AccessToken`. But nothing explains the original exception, which btw is not reproducible with the provided code.

Comment: But won't Load just bring whole AccessToken table from database to memory? Never used that method before.

Comment: @Evk I am not sure, I am still very new to EF.

Comment: @GertArnold would you recommend any other better way?

Comment: I still have a feeling we don't see the whole picture. But I would start modeling it as a real 1:1 relationship (i.e. AccessToken's PK is also its FK to User).

Comment: @GertArnold may be I am not providing important code (which I think it is not important), how is any object actually get tracked? what does that exactly mean? may be I am doing something somewhere else which makes it tracked.

Comment: Any object that is fetched from the database by EF, either through `Find`, LINQ, or `Load`, is stored in the context's cache and tracked for changes (unless you actively disable tracking). A context is an *identity map*, so only one copy of each entity can be tracked. When EF fetches entities, it will take care of this identity rule itself. Attaching entities to the context manually (for instance by adding them) can cause your problem. But that doesn't seem to happen in the visible code. Maybe this gives you a hint where to look further.

Comment: @GertArnold thank you for the explanation, I don't know actually what the problem can be, I removed that `.Load()` function and instead I am now using `.Include()` function, with that everything seems now to work fine.

Comment: Any idea why this error message occurred in the first place? I have the same problem right now. I am using `.Include()` to get the whole object and when I make a request to update it this error pops up. The `context` is `Scoped` so I suppose it should be a different instance - therefore the object should not be _already tracked_.

Comment: @Simonca Can you ask a new question and post your code, this error is normally code-dependent. So please ask a new question and post the link here so I may help you.

Comment: I thought about it but then I found this question which is very similar. I will post a new one and hope for a hint or useful answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that EF is already tracking `user` and the `AccessToken` in it. So, let's try to avoid getting another instance of the same entity and reuse the already tracked one.

Try

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DeleteAccessToken([FromBody]User user)
{
    // Requires System.Linq
    if (Context.Users.Any(u => u.Id == user.Id))
    {
        var accessTokenEntity = Context.AccessTokens.Find(user.AccessToken.Id); // Find the entity of the accesstoken (I tried also directly by accessing the navigation property of user entity)
        Context.AccessTokens.Remove(accessTokenEntity);

        // NOTE: You re not saving?
        return Ok();
    }
    else
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }
}
```

Alternatively try:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DeleteAccessToken([FromBody]User user)
{
    if (Context.Users.Any(u => u.Id == user.Id))
    {
        Context.AccessTokens.Remove(user.AccessToken);
        return Ok();
    }
    else
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a workaround with zero explanation about what caused the problem initially.

Comment: I thought the problem is well explained by the exception message. Seems like EF is already tracking the entity so I am trying to avoid getting another instance of the same (tracked) entity. Although, it's a mystery to me how EF can track the entity which just came from the `POST`.

Comment: I agree with Evk, it's about solving the mystery. Not about avoiding it.

Comment: Yes but why? It should not happen with OP code under normal usage.

Comment: @HristoYankov The first code worked, but I didn't understand why is that heppening, may I provide more info to understand why is that heppening? I didn't try the second code, but I guess it won't work maybe? because the `user` is just an object created from Json text, not refering to a database entry, am I right?

Comment: What's happening is EF is tracking `user` (in the arguments of the method). So instead of getting a new tracked entity (which causes the exception), we reuse it. WHY is EF tracking the `user` - I am not sure. maybe it's a EF-Core feature, or a setup in your project.

Comment: @HristoYankov when I executed the second code you suggested, I got the same mentioned exception, so which entity is being previously tracked which causes the exception is it the User entity or the AccessToken entity? because I am confused now.

Answer (score 0):

try replace this line:

```
var accessTokenEntity = Context.AccessTokens.Find(userEntity.AccessToken.Id);
```

to:

```
var accessTokenEntity = Context.AccessTokens.AsNoTracking().Find(userEntity.AccessToken.Id);
```