# Update, create or delete EF Core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an API where I want to be able to do a `PUT` request where I post a `Plan` with an array of `Blocks`. Right now, it automatically adds new `Block` entries and updates existing entries, but it doesn't delete entries if they're missing in the post.

These are the models:

```cs
public class Plan
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Block> Blocks { get; set; }
}

public class Block
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    public Plan Plan { get; set; }
}
```

And the controller action:

```cs
[HttpPut]
public ActionResult Update(Plan plan)
{
    if (plan?.Id == null) return BadRequest();

    var plans = _context.Plans.Count(p => p.Id == plan.Id);
    if (plans != 1) return NotFound();

    _context.Update(plan);

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return NoContent();
}
```

How would I go about implementing this? Is there a setting in EF to enable this?

I'm looking for a generic solution as there will be more collections and models which require the same functionality. I don't want to have to program this for every controller / action.

I'm using Entity Framework Core on .net core 2.2

Comment: Can you add the code sample where you update the `Plan` entity ?

Comment: @Fourat ofcourse, i added it

Comment: In a similar case like this I had to create an UpdateEntity method that takes the db entity and request entity. [here is a link to the more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57481485/5048820)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're keeping the principal entity (the `Plan` in your case) you should delete the deleted the child entities manually (the `Blocks`) :

```cs
[HttpPut]
public ActionResult Update(Plan plan)
{
    if (plan?.Id == null) return BadRequest();

    var plans = _context.Plans.Count(p => p.Id == plan.Id);
    if (plans != 1) return NotFound();

    var oldBlocks = _context.Blocks.Where(b => b.PlanId == plan.Id);
    foreach(var block in oldBlocks)
    {
        if (!plan.Blocks.Any(b => b.Id == block.Id))
            _context.Entry(block).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    _context.Update(plan);

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: I agree this would be the easy manual solution, however I'm looking for a more generic solution as there will be more collections and more models.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution is much cleaner.

```
[HttpPut]
public ActionResult Update(Plan plan)
{
    if (plan?.Id == null) return BadRequest();

    var oldPlan = _context.Plans
     .Where(p => p.Id == plan.Id)
     .Include(p => p.Blocks)
     .FirstOrDefault();

    if (oldPlan == null) return NotFound(); 

    oldPlan.Name = plan.Name;
    oldPlan.Blocks = plan.Blocks; //This will wipe out all the existing blocks and replace with new ones. If blocked are null it will just deleted all the existing blocks.

    _context.SaveChanges(); //No need of _context.Update(plan);

    return NoContent();
}
```