# EF Core with Lazy Loading tracks unreachable Objects?

Tags: asp.net, frameworks, entity, tracking

I am currently having troubles with entity framework core.

The application I am developing is supposed to help users plan their next business year by increasing/decreasing the quantity of a service they want to provide in the next year.

Based on their input the "worth" of a service is distributed pro rata to other "mini-services" that are contained in the changed service.

To do so I load the affected entries of the main service and the "mini-services" from Database via a repository which then uses Entity Framework.

```
public IEnumerable<OpsDistributionEntry> FilteredOpsDistributionEntries(int catalogId, IEnumerable<OpsDistributionEntry> filterEntries)
        {
            return _context.OpsDistributionEntries.FromSqlRaw(
                $"SELECT * FROM OpsDistributionEntries WHERE (Id IN (SELECT OpsEntriesId FROM DistributionCatalogOpsDistributionEntry WHERE CatalogsId = {catalogId}) " +
                $"AND EntityId IN ({string.Join(",", filterEntries.Select(x => x.EntityId))}))").ToList();
        }
```

I then map those database objects to my domain objects via constructor.

```
var opsDistributionEntries = new OpsDistributionEntriesFromDatabaseObjects(
                _repository.FilteredOpsDistributionEntries(_distCatalogId, _filterEntries));
```

```
public class OpsDistributionEntriesFromDatabaseObjects : IOpsDistributionEntries
    {
        private readonly IOpsDistributionEntries _distribution;

        public OpsDistributionEntriesFromDatabaseObjects(IEnumerable<DatabaseObjects.OpsDistributionEntry> distribution)
        {
            _distribution = new OpsDistributionEntries(distribution.Select(x => new OpsDistributionEntryFromDatabaseObject(x)));
        }

        public IEnumerator<IOpsDistributionEntry> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _distribution.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

```
public class OpsDistributionEntryFromDatabaseObject : IOpsDistributionEntry
    {
        public OpsDistributionEntryFromDatabaseObject(DatabaseObjects.OpsDistributionEntry opsDistributionEntry)
            : this(opsDistributionEntry.Id, opsDistributionEntry.TotalCases, opsDistributionEntry.TotalEffectiveWeight, opsDistributionEntry.Provide,
                opsDistributionEntry.Freeze,
                new OpsFromDatabaseObject(opsDistributionEntry.Entity),
                new DrgDistributionsFromDatabaseObjects(opsDistributionEntry.DrgDistribution))
        {
        }

        private OpsDistributionEntryFromDatabaseObject(int id, int totalCases, double totalEffectiveWeight, bool provide, bool freeze, IOps ops,
            IDrgDistributions drgDistribution)
        {
            Id = id;
            TotalCases = totalCases;
            TotalEffectiveWeight = totalEffectiveWeight;
            Provide = provide;
            Freeze = freeze;
            Ops = ops;
            DrgDistribution = drgDistribution;
        }

        public int Id { get; }
        public int TotalCases { get; }
        public double TotalEffectiveWeight { get; }
        public bool Provide { get; }
        public bool Freeze { get; }
        public IOps Ops { get; }
        public IDrgDistributions DrgDistribution { get; }
    }
```

```
public sealed class OpsFromDatabaseObject : IOps
    {
        public OpsFromDatabaseObject(DatabaseObjects.Ops ops) : this(ops.Id, ops.Code, ops.Description, ops.Year)
        {
        }

        private OpsFromDatabaseObject(int id, string code, string description, int year)
        {
            Id = id;
            Code = code;
            Description = description;
            Year = year;
        }

        public int Id { get; }
        public string Code { get; }
        public string Description { get; }
        public int Year { get; }
    }
```

I pass the database objects on to different levels, but finally every value is assigned and every possible navigation property is mapped to an domain object.

With those mapped domain objects I recalculate the new "worth" of the service and the correlated "mini-services".

After calculation I again map my Domain Objects to DatabaseObjects.

```
DatabaseObjects.OpsDistributionEntry ToDatabaseObject() => new DatabaseObjects.OpsDistributionEntry
        {
            Id = Id,
            EntityId = Ops.Id,
            Freeze = Freeze,
            Provide = Provide,
            TotalCases = TotalCases,
            TotalEffectiveWeight = TotalEffectiveWeight,
            DrgDistribution = DrgDistribution.Select(x => x.ToDatabaseObject()).ToImmutableList(),
        };
```

When I want to add those "updated" Objects to the context via repository

```
public void UpdateDistributionEntries(IEnumerable<OpsDistributionEntry> opsDistributionEntries)
        {
            if (opsDistributionEntries == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(opsDistributionEntries));
            _context.OpsDistributionEntries.UpdateRange(opsDistributionEntries);
        }
```

I am getting an Error that the Entities I want to updated are already being tracked by Entity Framework.

After some debugging I think that EF is still tracking the database objects I loaded for mapping the domain objects. I just use the database objects to map values to the domain objects and do not store any reference for them (as far as I understand).

Can any of you maybe tell me why they are still being tracked even if they are "unreachable". Or am I thinking wrong? Might this be because of Lazy Loading?

I've been debugging for almost 14 hours now :D Please someone give me a hint :D

Many thanks in advance

Comment: somehow the entities are already tracked by Entity Framework, I cannot be sure how, but I think if you simply use `context.SaveChanges()` the objects at the database would be updated, another possibility that you can use `.AsNoTracking()` when selecting the entities, check [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56240764/ef-core-another-instance-is-already-being-tracked) form more information

Comment: I already tried both. Save Changes just does absolutely nothing because the tracked entities aren’t changed just the mapped domain objects are changed. 
AsNoTracking() kills lazy loading. It would be a solution but I would like to understand why ef core is still tracking in my opinion unreachable entities ‍♂️

Comment: you can access the tracked entities by using `_context.ChangeTracker.Entries<MyEntity>();` find out more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/entity-entries)